# All about randomization

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2012, random

Im planning to make an entrance examination windows application in `vb.net,VS2012`, and i want to randomly select questions from database(i use ms sql server 2005 express) and not repeating every question. I have a limited idea in using binding navigator... is it possible to randomly select using binding navigator or if not do you have any ideas, suggestions,tutorials or articles that do you want to share? What s the best way/solutions to do this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim numberOfRecords As Integer
    Dim questionArray() As Integer
    Dim count As Integer = 0

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' Do logic here to load data from database

        ' Set the binding navigator's MoveNextItem property to nothing, because we are going to randomize the order instead of stepping through in order
        BindingNavigator.MoveNextItem = Nothing

        ' Get the number of records here from binding source
        numberOfRecords = BindingSource.Count

        ' Re-dimension array to size for total number of records
        ReDim questionArray(numberOfRecords)

        ' Initialize array of questions
        For i = 0 To numberOfRecords - 1
            questionArray(i) = i + 1
        Next

        ' Randomize the question array by moving items around
        For i = 0 To numberOfRecords - 1
            Dim swap As Integer = Int(((numberOfRecords - 1) * Rnd()) + 1)
            Dim num As Integer = questionArray(i)
            questionArray(i) = questionArray(swap)
            questionArray(swap) = num
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub BindingNavigatorMoveNextItem_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles BindingNavigatorMoveNextItem.Click
        BindingSource.Position = questionArray(count)

        ' Set the stopping point
        If count < numberOfRecords - 1 Then
            count = count + 1
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: thank you for your response! I will try this after i finished my existing project...